# Is it possible to implement (0..n) many to many (using @ManyToMany annotation) relation in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm looking for a way to implement (0..n) many to many relation in JPA, much possibly using @ManyToMany annotation. All examples that I found were about (1..n) relations. What I need to accomplish:
- I've got two entities: Contact and Tag. Each Contact can have 0..n Tags. Each Tag can have 0..n Contacts. From SQL point of view it would look like 
this: Contact (0..n) --- (1) Contact_has_Tag (1) --- (0..n) Tag.

Code below is not working for me because JPA is linking columns with INNER JOIN.

OFC I could do this using intermediate entity and @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations, but I want a simpler sollution.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(
    name = "contact_has_tag",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = true),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = true))
    private List<ContactTag> contactTags = new ArrayList<ContactTag>();

}

@Entity
@Data
public class ContactTag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="contactTags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();


}
```

Any ideas how it should be done?

Comment: If you use nullable=true it will become a 0-n

Comment: It would also persist your data if there is 0-n connection by default. Have you tried to persist on of this entities with a zero sized list on many-to-many? If not try it - if you already have - what´s the error?

Comment: @LenglBoy - I will try to attack it from Model/Code level - for now I've been inserting data trough DB query - but when I tried retrieving it from Java JPA built query with INNER JOINS, so depicting relation 1..n... Maybe in that case I should try recreating DB model, but anyway I don't see anything blocking 0..n relation. nullable=true is set.

Comment: Can you remove @JsonIgnore and try.